# CORS error when trying to call get API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, cors

I am trying to get HTML data from any website using get API.

I have this URL: `https://www.linkedin.com/`

I am trying to get HTML page as text from this URL.

What I tried:

```
  getData() {
    const api = "https://www.linkedin.com/";
    return this.httpClient.get(api, { responseType: "text" });
  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData().subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
```

I got this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.linkedin.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What did I miss?

Comment: you can't access resources cross origin unless that server allows it.

Comment: but if i have credential username and password for my linked in i can access it ? @Daniel A. White

Comment: no - please read up on cors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score -2):

You need to have proxy requests to enable CORS in your angular application.
For doing this, simply create a proxy.config.json file and enter something like this.

```
{
 "/api": {
 "target": "http://localhost:5000",
 "secure": false
 }
}
```

You then need to inform angular about this configuration. You can do this by adding a proxyConfig option inside your angular.json file.

```
"architect": {
"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "application-name:build",
"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.json"
},
```

Comment: This did not work for me.